# changing default (man) pager

Tags: bash, man, pager

I'm working on Solaris 10, using bash. Want to change default pager from "more" to "less" (because "less is more" :). Tried to do the following:

```
PAGER=less
```

PS. When I do it in csh via

```
setenv PAGER less
```

then it works

Comment: Do not use just `less` since the default is to use `more -s`. `less` seems to implement the same option. BTW: if you have an editor that allows you to exit a binary without destroing the binary, edit `/usr/bin/man` and replace `nroff -u0` by `nroff -u1` for better readable output. IIRC, there are three such strings in the binary.

Comment: @schily; I think you wanted to say _edit a binary_ and not _exit a binary_, right? Hm, not sure that I have such a thing, what would it be, some hexeditor? I can see the strings with _strings_.Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Ok, it seems that I made 2 typos and fixed only one. Any modern editor schould be able to so this, `vi` is not usable.

Comment: Notice the (small but important) distinction with [`setenv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) saying that it sets *environment* variables.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I do notice. The thing is that with `csh` I have more experience and still fighting my way through `bash`. Up to now I was even thinking that Bash doesn't make a distinction between environment and any other variable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your

```
PAGER=less
```

sets the *shell variable* `PAGER` to the value `less`.  For `man` (or anything other than the current shell) to see this, you will have to additionally make `PAGER` an *environment variable*.  You do this with `export`, either through

```
PAGER=less
export PAGER
```

or

```
export PAGER=less
```

A shell variable is "exported into the environment" with `export`.  This is the same in all `sh`-like shells.  Exporting a variable in this way is the corollary to the `csh`/`tcsh` [`setenv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) command.